# Getting Started with Lagom gives Runtime Exception

Tags: java, microservices, typesafe, lagom

Installed Activator as:

`brew install typesafe-activator`

Created a new project as:

`activator new my-first-system lagom-java`

Change to the directory and running the project as `activator run` gives:

`[info] Set current project to my-first-system (in build file:/Users/arungupta/workspaces/my-first-system/)
[info] Updating {file:/Users/arungupta/workspaces/my-first-system/}my-first-system...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[info] Done updating.
java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected.
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last my-first-system/compile:run for the full output.
[error] (my-first-system/compile:run) No main class detected.
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed Mar 23, 2016 12:08:22 PM`

Here is the JDK version:

`java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)`

What's missing?

Answer (score 4):

There is no main class to run on the root project, and that's the reason for the exception. To start all your Lagom services use `runAll`, see [the Lagom getting started documentation](http://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.0.x/GettingStarted.html#Running-Lagom-services).

By the way, we have [a ticket](https://github.com/lagom/lagom/issues/21) for making `run` an alias of `runAll` when the task is executed on the root project.

Answer (score -1):

Just do an `activator` instead of `activator run` then do a `runAll` as recommended above and in the getting started guide.